# Is there a better way - Union All/Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables with data as -

```
TestTable1                          TestTable2  
----------                          ----------  
Id  Name        DealDate            Id  Name        DealDate  
1   aaTable     2010-09-22          1   aaTable2    2010-09-23  
2   bbTable     2010-09-23          2   bbTable2    2010-09-24  
3   ccTable     2010-09-28          3   ccTable2    2010-09-26  
4   ddTable     2010-09-25          4   ddTable2    2010-09-27
```

I want to have only *two* latest records from resultset of TestTable1 + TestTable2 to return this -

```
Id  Name        DealDate
4   ccTable     2010-09-28 
3   ddTable2    2010-09-27
```

This is my current query

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT TOP 2 Id, Name, DealDate FROM TestTable1 ORDER BY DealDate DESC) T1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT TOP 2 Id, Name, DealDate FROM TestTable2 ORDER BY DealDate DESC) T2
) T1T2
ORDER BY DealDate DESC
```

Can anyone please guide me for a better way (performance-wise/readability wise) to achieve this?

P.S. Above tables are just to present the use-case, my actual tables have thousands of records.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you actually having a performance problem with this approach?

Comment: If the two latest deals are in the same table, did you want only those two latest ones?  Or do you always want one from TestTable1 and one from TestTable2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I would change performance wise is to remove the `ORDER BY` and the `TOP 2` in the inner selects - they are pointless.
Other than that, your solution is the way to go. There shouldn't be any performance problems as you are using `UNION ALL` and not `UNION`...

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM 
(
    SELECT Id, Name, DealDate FROM TestTable1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Id, Name, DealDate FROM TestTable2
) T1T2
ORDER BY DealDate DESC
```

Comment: Thnx for your reply! I added *ORDER BY/TOP n* in sub-query because I was thinking it will give a better performance because I am filtering out unnecessary records before UNION ALL. But after you pointed out, I run above query on actual table with TOP 90000 records for a test and found it is actually slower than what I expected - So I have removed *ORDER BY/TOP n* from inner query. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you always wanted to have 1 record from TestTable1 and 1 record from TestTable2, then you could try:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TestTable1 ORDER BY DealDate DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TestTable2 ORDER BY DealDate DESC
```

Otherwise the other answers should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Why not simply `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TestTable1 order by dealdate desc UNION ALL SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TestTable2 order by dealdate desc`?